# Modify a file without creating another file

Tags: files, text-processing, scripting

Is there a way to modify a file without writing the contents to another file, without `sed` and `awk`?

For example:

```
$ cat test.txt
aaa
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Replacing using `sed` with `-i` option, `sed -i 's/aaa/NNN/g' test.txt` will produce the following:

```
NNN
NNN
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

How to do that without `awk` and `sed`?

Comment: by the way, `sed -i` internally writes to a temporary file and then moves it into the place of the original file. The option title `--in-place` is a little misleading.

Comment: The vi and sponge solutions also create temporary files to do their work...

Comment: My intention to post this question is that atleast the user should not manually create a new file and write the contents. Thank you for simple answers and comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a `vi` script:

```
$ vi test.txt -c '%s/aaa/NNN/ | wq'
$ cat test.txt
NNN
NNN
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

You're simply automating what would normally be entered when using `vi` in command mode (accessed using <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> usually):

`%` - carry out the following command on every line:

`s/aaa/NNN/` - subtitute `aaa` with `NNN`

`|` - command delimiter

`w` - write changes to file

`q` - quit

Comment: seems very neat and simple.

Comment: I was using your script for replacing tab with comma. `vi test.txt -c '%s/\t/,/**g** | wq'` did well for multiple columns. Without `g`, it was only replacing the first instance. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Using [sponge](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge):

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern='aaa'
replacement='NNN'

while read -r line
do                                                                              
  printf '%s\n' "${line//$pattern/$replacement}"
done < "${1}"
```

Call with:

```
./script.sh test.txt | sponge test.txt
```

Comment: yours too ;-) Never heard of `sponge` before.

Comment: I found it here: http://tools.suckless.org/sbase

Comment: That script suffers from multiple issues. (1) `read line` should be `read -r line`. (2) The `$()` in the `if` is redundant. I'm surprised if that even works. (3) `echo` suffers from a lot of portability issues even within bash. Use `printf '%s\n' "${var}"` instead. (4) `$1` should be wrapped in double quotes: `"$1"`.

Comment: Also, if it's a bash script, you can just do `grep -q "$pattern" <<< "$line"`.

Comment: I think you forgot to define `pattern` and `replacement`, too.

Comment: I submitted an edit with some improvements. While it may not exactly be suitable for an edit, I'm hoping to save you some work.

Comment: thanks @nyuszika7h for suggesting multiple improvements. The script was a quick (sloppy) submission. If there are issues left, please let me know - I'm always keen on improving. E.g. I didn't know that `echo` has any issues. I'll check that.

Comment: sponge command seems to do similar function as redirection operator but changing contents in the same file. I could not find it in my linux distribution.

Comment: It's  not a standard tool, but I think it deserves more publicity. See the link above , for download and source.

Comment: sponge is packaged in [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/); Debian, Ubuntu and other distributions have it as an optional package in their repositories.

Answer (score 12):

With [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/ed.html), the line editor:

```
ed -s test.txt <<< $',s/pattern/replace/g\nw\nq'
```

or

```
ed -s test.txt <<IN
,s/pattern/replace/g
w
q
IN
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' ,s/pattern/replace/g w q | ed -s test.txt
```

Comment: @mikeserv - wrt `ed` & temp file creation, it all depends on the implementation; see the posts [here](http://www.unix.com/answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/202403-edit-file-place-overwriting-original.html) by _bakunin_ and _alister_.

Comment: Is there some advantage to using `ed` over using `ex`?

Comment: @Wildcard - I've never had any interest in `ex` (and as a result, I've never used it - same for `vi`). I only know that on some exotic setups you may find `ed` but not `ex`. Other than that I'm afraid I can't answer your question. Someone like Stéphane - who knows the ins and outs of both - would be the right guy to ask.

Comment: Both are specified in POSIX, and `ex` is more flexible.  But thanks for explaining.  :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `bash` or `ksh`, you can use pattern substitution for shell variables. Note however, that basic shell globs are less powerful and extended shell globs have some features that sed doesn't and vice versa. For more details, see 'Parameter Expansion' in `man 1 bash`:

```
t=$(< test.txt); printf '%s\n' "${t//aaa/NNN}" >test.txt
```

Extended shell globs are disabled by default, so you may need to explicitly enable them:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: I can't see any globs there.

Comment: @nyuszika7h true, although it is possible if you want to, like so: `printf '%s\n' "${t//+(a|d)/NNN}"` if you wanted to replace all runs of 'a's or 'd's with 'NNN'

Answer (score 4):

You can also use perl

```
perl -pi -e 's/aaa/bbb/g' file.txt
```

This will give the output you desire.

You can also backup your original file automatically using `i.bak` instead of `i`. This will create a backup named file.txt.bak.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/aaa/NNN/|x' test.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close